# Expand lines with multiple data entries into individual lines with one piece of data each

Tags: bash, parsing, text, awk, grep

I have a file in which the first column is an identifier and the rest of each line contains zero to multiple digits separated by single spaces.

For example:

```
SOAP.k35.scaffold280 0003723 
SOAP.k35.scaffold421 
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 0004930 0016021
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 0006457 0005509 0030246 0051082 0005788
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 0007411 0033627 0035001 0016321 0007507 0035011 0007498 0045886 0030155 0030334 0045995 0034446 0005102 0030424 0005604 0030054 0036062 0008021
```

I would like to have each trailing digit entry on its own line with the appropriate first column identifier (i.e. SOAP... or TRINITY....) leading each line with an appended " = " between each first column identifier and the given number for that line. I'd also like to remove lines that contain no digits after the first column identifier.

As an example of what I would the result of the processed text above to be:

```
SOAP.k35.scaffold280 = 0003723
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 = 0004930
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 = 0016021
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0006457
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0005509
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0030246
```

...
and so forth.

My primary issue is knowing how to store that first column identifier to insert ahead of any new line characters I am inserting when parsing lines by the numerical data entries.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '(/^SOAP/ || /^TRINITY/){for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1" = "$i}}' Input_file
```

In case you don't want to strict `awk` program only for lines which are starting either with string `SOAP` or `TRINITY` then try following.

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1" = "$i}}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
SOAP.k35.scaffold280 = 0003723
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 = 0004930
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 = 0016021
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0006457
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0005509
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0030246
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0051082
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0005788
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0007411
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0033627
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0035001
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0016321
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0007507
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0035011
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0007498
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0045886
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0030155
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0030334
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0045995
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0034446
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0005102
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0030424
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0005604
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0030054
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0036062
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0008021
```

Comment: `NF>1` is redundant since you start the loop from `i=2`

Comment: @Dzienny, I have put it so that if only SOAP or TRINITY strings are there in any line nothing else then it should not go to that lint.

Comment: Still you can leave SOAP and TRINITY but omit the `&& NF>1` part and it will work the same.

Answer (score 1):

simply,

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,"=",$i}' file

SOAP.k35.scaffold280 = 0003723
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 = 0004930
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 = 0016021
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0006457
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0005509
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0030246
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0051082
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0005788
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl also

```
$ perl -ne ' ($x)=$_=~m/(^\S+)/; while( /\s(\d+)/g ) { print "$x = $1\n" } ' scottc.txt
SOAP.k35.scaffold280 = 0003723
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 = 0004930
SOAP.k35.scaffold429 = 0016021
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0006457
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0005509
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0030246
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0051082
TRINITY_DN23171_c1_g1_i2 = 0005788
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0007411
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0033627
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0035001
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0016321
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0007507
SOAP.k35.scaffold599 = 0035011
. . . . . 
. . . . .
```